# What technologies of Spring Framework do we use for creating real Enterprise applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java EE (rather enterprise application development) and initially i started off with EJB. After a while, and based on some research i decided to learn (and eventually to work) using Spring Framework.

I now spent almost 2 months in learning Spring framework (using materials in internet and some books) and i have fair understanding of Core Spring (Like DI, AOP etc.). I have worked on a full scale enterprise application (bug fixing project) for 2-3 months and in that project we used: EJB 3.x along with other technologies.

Using Spring Framework, it has MVC support (web-applications). I am having difficulty in understanding for some of the things as to how it is done using Spring Framework, which i have listed below and it would help me if you spare your valuable time to share your inputs:

1) Full-blown Enterprise applications typically use Application servers (like JBOSS or alike), it is possible to have a spring application which is deployed in Apache tomcat  only and in terms of functionality equal to full-blown Java EE application?

2) I read Spring framework simplifies the work which is achieved by EJB (in a typical Java EE application) and without using Application server, if this is true, then the above point should be true? Is my understanding correct here?

3) Like Business is implemented in EJBs (mainly in Session EJBs), what is the equivalent we have in Spring?

And finally, for writing a complex real time Enterprise application, what spring technologies / sub-project are needed to learn?

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all, Spring is not a Java EE  application server.  Spring is only a framework which allows 3 things basically: dependency injection, proxies and Java EE abstractions.

1) Tomcat is not a Full Java EE Compliant Server and you cannot "complete" server with Spring.

2) Spring can simplify Java EE Clients development without an Application Client environment, for example using the SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean to access EJB clients.

3) Spring supports exporting beans for communication in a client-server architecture, using Hessian or Burlap exporter for example.

Last, I've never used any realtime library.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, the answer to this question could lead to multiple books and several flame wars, but I try myself to keep it civil.

1) Yes and no. A short comparison of Spring and Java EE 
Short: As long as you are not afraid of using parts of the Java EE stack like JPA or JSF (if you need those), and you don't need real JTA transaction handling against multiple datasources and you don't need any other advanced stuff from Java EE, Spring + ORM Framework + Webframework on Tomcat is as powerful as Java EE  on an full-blown Application Server.

To break things up a little:

- Springs Core DI container is on par with the different CDI implementations
- Springs own persistence framework (Spring JDBC) is less powerfull than the JPA Standard, however you easily can use any even a container managed JPA
- Springs MVC framework is more a low-level framework than the JSF standard, however you can easily use that one as well
- Springs MVC framework is also well suited for REST apps, about on the same level as the JAX-RS standard

So you can mix and match it as you like, one of the good things about Spring is, that is has nearly no "vendor tie in" regarding third party libraries, and no one forces you to use a part that you don't need or don't like.

2) It has been true up until the more recent Java EE standards, however nowadays with CDI, I'd say Java EE has caught up and developing Java EE Apps is as simple.

3) A simple singleton bean. Probably with a Transactional annotation.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Full-blown Enterprise applications typically use Application
>   servers (like JBOSS or alike), it is possible to have a spring
>   application which is deployed in Apache tomcat only and in terms of
>   functionality equal to full-blown Java EE application?

Correct, Jboss, Weblogic, Websphere are some of the most widely used application servers in the market. These servers are required if you need EJB (Session Beans, Entity Beans, Message Driven Beans), Messaging, RMI and other middleware support. Remember Tomcat, Jetty etc (http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers) are webservers. So you have to decide if you need a App server or a Webserver completely based on your business requirement

> 2) I read Spring framework simplifies the work which is achieved by
>   EJB (in a typical Java EE application) and without using Application
>   server, if this is true, then the above point should be true? Is my
>   understanding correct here?

Nothing is easy in this world ;). Spring supports Transaction Management, Persistance, Security and other features that were only available for EJB's. Moreover Spring provides other benefits like AOP, DI etc.

> 3) Like Business is implemented in EJBs (mainly in Session EJBs), what
>   is the equivalent we have in Spring?

You have @Service in Spring. The class containing your business code can be specifically annotated with @Service or generally with @Component